# Access to associations from polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have next models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now I can get posts and articles via `@comment.commentable`, but I need via `@comment.post` or `@comment.article`. I found some solutions, but it's not working with nested attributes:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :article
accepts_nested_attributes_for :post
```

My `comments_controller`:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

    if @comment.save!
      head :ok, location: @comment
    else
      render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(
      :text, text: {},
      post_attributes: [:id, text: {}],
      article_attributes: [:id, text: {}]
    )
  end
end
```

Post params from form like:

```
    const params = {
      comment: {
        text,
        post_attributes: [{
          id: post ? post.id : null,
          text,
        }]
      }
    }
```

If post or article not exists it must be created. Or add one more model like here https://gist.github.com/runemadsen/1242485 — but I don't want to do that :(

Comment: does it make sense to create `comment` for nothing? I mean to say that a comment must be for either articel or post. makes sense?

Comment: Yes, comment can be created for nothing, but in this case there is a post or article text in params, and `@comment.save` create post and comment together. Or comment can be create for exists post or article.

Comment: Can you post code of nested forms?

Comment: Form on React, so I can show axios post params:
```
    const params = {
      comment: {
        text,
        post_attributes: [{
          id: post ? post.id : null,
          text,
        }]
      }
    }
```
Add params to question body.